# How to get IR codes of Magformers RC?

Tags: remote-control

Some of [Magformers blocks](http://www.magformersworld.com/GHome/rue/products/product_view.asp?PCD=126) comes with Remote Controller:

[image]

The controller is lost. Is there any way to get RC codes to use with some universal remotes (for ex., with Moes UFO-R11 or with Android app [irplus](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.binarymode.android.irplus&hl=en))?

I tried RCs from other devices and also tried hundreds of devices from `irplus`, but it didn't help.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because even though we accept questions about other clone brands that produce LEGO-like elements, but in this particular case it isn't related to bricks of any form or brand.

Comment: @Alex, there are similar questions about ir codes on this site.

Comment: It's not the IR codes that are relevant in this case (otherwise TV remotes were on topic too), but the nature of building blocks. While a point can be made about Magformers being a building system, IMO it's sufficiently different from LEGO and its on-topic clones that it might not belong on this site (just like with KNEX).